# Concrete5 Custom Ajax in Block View

Tags: php, ajax, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

On Concrete5-8.1.0 I have created a custom block with Ajax functionality based largely on the concrete5 docs - [Implementing Ajax in Block View Templates](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-blocks/creating-a-new-block-type/implementing-ajax-block-view-templates). However, unlike the example I do not want to reload the block view, I want to pass specific messages based on the input. I tried a simple `echo '{"msg":"ok"}';` and `return '{"msg":"ok"});` as a test, but requests to the function yielded an empty response.

I found [How To Send JSON Responses with Concrete5.7](http://saimiri.io/2016/03/send-json-responses-with-concrete-57/) and used Option 2 (for greater control of error codes) resulting in the following test code:

```
public function action_submit($token = false, $bID = false) {

  if ($this->bID != $bID) {
    return false;
  }
  if (Core::make('token')->validate('get_paper', $token)) {

    //save to database
    //removed for brevity

    //send email
    if ($this->emailto != '') {
      //removed for brevity
    }

    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
      return new Response(
        json_encode(array('msg' => 'ok')),
        200,
        ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
      );
    } else {
      Redirect::page($page)->send();
    }
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
  exit;
}
```

The database save and email function as expected, but the response is still empty. In Chrome Dev Tools, I see the correct Content-Type (as a test, I tried `text/html` and saw that change in dev tools), but no content. Interestingly, if I change the status from `200` to `500` I not only see the status change reflected in dev tools, I also see the `{"msg":"ok"}` content that I'm expecting, but changing the status back to `200` and the content is again empty.

It seems I'm missing something simple... I have verified that all caching is turned off within C5 (site is still in development), I have also verified the jQuery request includes `cache:false`, but the solution escapes me.

Comment: Did you find a solution?